# Is there any way to rewrite existing php file from php script

Tags: php, html, zip

I built a website from native php and I wanted for my users so they can be able to change the index.php without manualy write the code, what I mean here is:

I've been building some kind of "upload theme" system, it allows my users for upload a zip file. which is contain

- js(folder)
- css(folder)
- image(folder)
- index.html

after uploading and extracting a zip file, I need to change "index.html" to "index.php" and inject my php script to that index.php Like

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>...</html>
```

> and It will be index.php

```
<?php include ('myscript.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>...</html>
```

Is it possible to do that from single click php execution?

Comment: You could use a combination of `rename()` and `file_put_contents()` easily enough.

Comment: Do you have some of the script that shows how you unzip and place the files where they need to be?

Comment: oh dang!. i'm a fool. `file_put_contents()` is the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is what you could do:

```
# Template file
$file       =   __DIR__.'/index.html';
# What you want to add
$prepend    =   '<?php include(\'/my/file.php\') ?>';
# Get contents of index.html
$raw        =   file_get_contents($file);
# Save the content back
file_put_contents($file,$prepend.PHP_EOL.$raw);
# Rename the file
rename($file,__DIR__.'/index.php');
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is explaining my solution so well!.

Comment: You could also design it so that when they upload the file, it decompresses to a `template` folder your `index.php` checks if there is a template folder and instead includes their file into your default index page. That way, you don't really have to mess with the contents of their document and change it in any way.

Comment: Doing that kind of system allows the site to be able to switch templates at will (if that is what you are planning on doing, I don't know if that is relevant or not).

Comment: What I am doing right now is very simple, if there's a folder that I mention above is exist, my script will execute to delete that folder before uploading zip file. I'm a newbie in php. so I'll follow your suggestion in my future update for my system.